# Error inside node_modules while trying to run unit tests with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

Edit:
Same error happens when I try to import highcharts directly into a test, commenting out any other setupFile

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'highcharts')

      1 | import * as React from 'react';
      2 | // import Home from './Home';
    > 3 | import highcharts from 'highcharts';
        | ^
      4 | import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
      5 | // import { render } from 'jest-utils';
      6 |

      at node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:2499:9
      at apply (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:29:25)
      at _registerModule (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:108:5)
      at factory (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:13:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:9:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/components/Home/Home.spec.js:3:1)
```

---

Currently, I'm trying to integrate react-testing-library (with jest, babel, webpack) to an old React project, I've updated React to 17.0.2 (latest possible version without crashing the whole project), and now I'm stuck at a weird error. Basically, when importing highcharts from one of my setup files, an error inside the node_modules pointing at the library happens.

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'highcharts')

      1 | import toastr from 'toastr';
    > 2 | import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
        | ^
      3 | import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
      4 | import i18next from './i18n';
      5 | import networkgraph from 'highcharts/modules/networkgraph';

      at node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:2499:9
      at fn (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:29:25)
      at _registerModule (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:108:5)
      at factory (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:13:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:9:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/vendor.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/i18n.js:14:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/ErrorHandlers/utils/GetErrorMessage.js:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/stores/UserStore/UserStore.js:15:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/Request.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/components/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotesStore.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/components/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes.js:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scripts/components/Home/Home.spec.js:2:1)
```

The last file that is traceable is the `vendos.js`  that just imports the `highchart` like it's showing in the error preview.
This is the Jest config: https://pastebin.com/jt2L8ijQ

The project is running/compiling with no problem.

I tried to add `highcharts` to `transformIgnorePatterns`  like so:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(highcharts)/)'],
// or adding to moduleNameMapper
moduleNameMapper: {
    highcharts: require.resolve('highcharts'),
    ...
  }
```

But those changes had no difference, same result as before.
Tried updating highcharts too, but it ended up breaking some stuff.
I'm lost, don't really know what to do, if anyone needs extra info, ask away.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I found why the error was happening.
In this project the highchart is using JQuery, and I was setting it incorretly, instead of setting up a `setupFile.js`, and adding to it like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

I was wrongly defining it inside my `jest.config.js` like so:

```
{
...
   globals: {
     "jQuery": require("jquery")
   }
...
}
```

And these errors:

```
at node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:2499:9
at apply (node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js:29:25)
```

It was guiding me to the wrong file, the actual file where the Type Error was happening was a `highcharts` build where it was trying to get a `highcharts` from the jQuery, this part in particular:

```
B.jQuery.fn.highcharts=function()
```

After all this weird debugging, I got it to run.